# Are there any errors in the computation of the earth surface area

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

The surface area of earth might be completed using the formula A=4pe *r^2.
For the surface area of a sphere of radius r. Are there any errors in the computation of the earth surface area using the above formula?  Explain.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts at all? What would it mean for the computation to be error-free?

Comment: Is surface of the Earth a sphere?

Comment: @PatrickStevens i think there is an error in calculating pe.

Comment: There will be an error in calculating the radius.

Answer (score 2):

This formula is correct if you assume the Earth is a perfect smooth sphere. It's not - it's an ellipsoid with a very bumpy surface, so the formula is only an approximation. It's a pretty good one, though.

The wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth has data on how the radius from the center to the poles isn't the same as from the center to the equator.

Measuring the surface area taking bumpiness into account is a much harder problem.